# How do I uninstall Erlang R16B-03.18.el7 so I can install Erlang 25.0.3?

Tags: linux, rabbitmq, erlang

The R16B version isn't working with the latest version of RabbitMQ I'm trying to install on my VM (needs 23.3 or later) and I already tried to install 25.0.3 but it won't install because it's conflicting with the R16B files that exist.

```
file /usr/bin/typer from install of esl-erlang-25.0.3-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package erlang-typer-R16B-03.18.el7.x86_64
```

That's the error I get. I tried `rm -r erlang*.rpm` and it asks for a reboot after completing but still gives the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this command you just delete the rpm. What you want is to deinstall the rpm. You could use

```
dnf uninstall PACKAGENAME
```

where, in your case, PACKAGENAME whould be something like erlang-typer-R16B-03.18.el7.

Comment: Tried that and it said ```-bash: dnf: command not found```

Comment: What system do you use?

Comment: To uninstall an rpm you can also use rpm -e packagename.rpm

Comment: Just trying to install a rabbitmq server on the vm I created. CentOS 7 (via Git Bash) on Windows.

Now it says ```error: package erlang-typer-R16B-03.18.el7.rpm is not installed``` after I ran ```rpm -e erlang-typer-R16B-03.18.el7.rpm```

So frustrating. I've been on this for hours when it should have just been a minor issue.

Comment: Try `rpm -qa` to get the list of installed rpms. In this list, search for erlang packages. You clould also install it and then uninstall it. This could help, if you modified the system in a way, that you shouldn't...

Comment: That definitely did the trick. Had to scroll and pick out each erlang file to remove piece by piece but it worked. I really appreciate the help. You're a life saver!